# Pasar un arreglo de manera dinamica, a la sintaxis de un IN en SQL mediante JDBC en JAVA

Tags: java

Un ejemplo burdo de lo que necesito para que tengan una idea es lo siguiente:

```
 SELECT name,last_name 
 FROM employees    
 WHERE employee.name 
 IN('sstan','Ivan Botero','Stefan Nolde','Jose Javier 
 Segura','jose','Miguel Osorio','etc');
```

Es decir que mediante conexión con JDBC, tener una query a la cual le pase una lista de elementos dentro del **IN** mediante codigo java. concatenando y separando con comas y comillas simples cada elemento de la lista.

Otro ejemplo burdo **(ya que no puedo colocar la query en cuestion pero para terminos de ejemplo sirve como referencia)**, seria algo como lo siguiente en java:

```
String Query = "SELECT name,lastname "
+"FROM employees "
+"WHERE lastname  IN ("+ lista_con_nombres.toSting() +") " +
```

Comment: Hola F.Lopez. Por favor agrega más detalle de la pregunta para que los lectores podamos comprender mejor tu problema.

Comment: El problema es la pregunta, no se entiende tu problema, lo digo a nivel general, un usuario que tenga un problema similar al tuyo quizás no pueda encontrar de manera sencilla que tú ya has tenido este problema.

Comment: @F.Lopez, bienvenido a StackOverflow, te invito a leer [¿cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), y luego a que edites tu pregunta y nos digas por lo menos, qué es lo que estás intentando realizar, y cuál es el problema que tienes para lograrlo.

Comment: Se edito la pregunta de manera correcta, en ese entonces cuando se cerro no tenia el conocimiento suficiente para abordar la pregunta de una manera mas sencilla y fácil de entender para los usuarios. Se agrego código de referencia y ejemplos de lo que se necesita y ademas de una respuesta acorde al tema, pido reabrir esta pregunta, para que nuevos usuarios o personas que tengan el mismo problema tengan la facilidad de solucionarlos. Gracias !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## La solución fue la siguiente:

En el primer append concateno comillas simples, en el segundo append concateno el elemento, en el tercer append concateno la ultima comilla simple, en el cuarto append concateno la coma para el siguiente elemento.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

for (int i = 0; i < lista_con_nombres.size(); i++){  
    sb.append("'").append(lista_con_nombres.get(i)).append("'").append(",");
    sb.deleteCharAt( sb.length() -1 ).toString();
}
```

Aquí elimino la ultima coma de la cadena ya que no es necesaria.

```
 sb.deleteCharAt( sb.length() -1 ).toString();
```

---

### A tener en cuenta

Tener cuidado con la inyección SQL, como recomendo el usuario @jachguate, en mi caso esta solución era para un formulario con un datapicker en donde solo se seleccionaba una fecha pero no se ingresaban datos, en su caso si esos datos vienen del input de un formulario deben tener cuidado en como validan los datos de entrada en su aplicación.

Comment: Cuidado. Esto funciona bien para MySQL, pero en Oracle si hay más de 1000 elementos dentro de `IN` te lanza una excepción.

Comment: Bueno, en este momento estoy utilizando oracle, que bueno tener en cuenta que puede ocurrir este problema, de todos modos la lista varia desde 10 elementos hasta 300 por el momento, por otro lado si algún día se tuviera que aumentar esta lista a mas de 1000 elementos que podría ser factible en un futuro, ya que es una lista de sucursales las cuales van aumentando cada día que se implementan en producción  hasta hoy existen casi 300. bueno fuera de eso esto funciona dentro de un bloque try catch, por si se llegara a dar el caso. Gracias y saludos.

Comment: Ojo, que este código es vulnerable a inyección SQL. Entiendo que `sucIds` en este caso no viene del usuario, pero creo que sería bueno alertar de esta situación en la solución o bien brindar una solución que no sea vulnerable, ya que futuros visitantes podrían estar concatenando datos capturados del usuario.

Comment: Hola @jachguate ,  La idea principal de esta solución, mas allá de evitar una inyección SQL, es poder hacer la **concatenación para luego dejar la lista dentro del** `IN`, es decir me estoy apegando mas a la solución a la pregunta que en como evitar inyecciones SQL en la aplicación, de todas formas **ALERTAR** a los usuarios que no saben es muy buena recomendación, ya que pueden caer en estas practicas. Gracias por este punto de vista.